# What is equivalent to Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection in c#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a method which takes a stored procedure name and a [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.collection.aspx)?  I am referencing a vb project in which I have to pass in a collection to this method, but the current project I am in is in c#, so I am unclear what I can pass into the method?

Here is the vb call:

```
public void CallStoredProc(string spName, Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection params);
```

In my c# app, I need to call this an pass in the appropriate c# object to params.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One option is to simply use the `Collection` type directly from C#.  This is a standard type in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` assembly and can be used from any .Net language.

The closest collection in the standard BCL though is `Hashtable`.  Converting between `Hashtable` and `Collection` should be fairly straight forward

For example

```
using VBCollection = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection;
...
public static VBCollection ToVBCollection(this Hashtable table) {
  var collection = new VBCollection();
  foreach (var pair in table) {
    // Note: The Add method in collection takes value then key.
    collection.Add(pair.Value, pair.Key);  
  }
  return collection;
}
```

Note: This is not a direct mapping though.  The `Collection` type supports a number of operations which `Hashtable` does not like: before and after values, index by number or key, etc ...  My approach would be to use one type consistently throughout the application and change either the C# or VB project appropriately

Comment: ok, I will give this a shot, I was under the impression that you could not mix vb and c# code in the same assembly

Comment: You can't mix it. That doesn't mean you can't use types from each others libraries...

Comment: You can't mix code, but you're perfectly fine referencing assemblies written in VB and C#.

Comment: I decided to take the approach of just referencing the Microsoft.VisualBasic dll and using its Collection class.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you can change the method, so that it takes `ICollection`, `IEnumerable` or their generic variants, you *have to* pass an instance of `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection` to that method.

From the point of view of C#, `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection` is just a class and you can work with it as with any other class, i.e. instance it:

```
new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection()
```

Of course, you have to reference the assembly Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll in your project.

Comment: +1 For the idea of changing the method to take an IEnumerable. There is a way to get the compiler to help you avoid future problems: mark the VB assembly as [CLS compliant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a7a7h3.aspx) and the compiler will warn you if you do anything that makes your code hard to call from C#, or any other language

Comment: @MarkJ, except that `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection` *is* CLS-compliant, so there will be no warning in this case.

Comment: Oops, my mistake, sorry (blush)

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a "C# object", or a "VisualBasic.net object" - it is all .net, so you can simply include a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll and use that Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection.

C# devs often frown upon Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll because of the name, but you won't be eaten by Velociraptors if you use it since .net is properly and fully language-independent.

Comment: I understand, when I said object, I just was just referring to the actual reference being passed into the method.

Comment: Yeah, raptors prey only on those who use `goto`.

Comment: I know this answer is a bit old, but I thought I would point out that there is good reason to move away from this object, where possible.  Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection is not thread-safe, as noted in the documentation.  This may not matter to your code, but it is something to keep in mind.

Comment: @Sean indeed, but AFAIK none of the collections are outside of the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace. Which are prefereable if you actually have multithreading.