# Collection() in C#? (moving code from VB.Net to C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-mobile-6.5

I am migrating code from VB.Net to C# for Windows Mobile 6 applications.

Portion of that code is using Collection() from Microsoft.VisualBasic.

```
Private tbNew As New Collection
```

However, when I tried to use Collection() in C#, it gives me error. I guess such type does not exist.

What can I use instead?

Comment: there is `Collection<T>` in C#

Comment: Down voting . Because this seems to be very easy to find http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybcx56wz.aspx#BKMK_VisualBasic or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115194/what-is-equivalent-to-microsoft-visualbasic-collection-in-c

Comment: I can't find Collection at all in compact version for Windows Mobile 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use List

```
List<string> tbNew = new List<string>();
tbNew.Add("cat");
tbNew.Add("dog");
```

Or Dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, int> tbNew = new Dictionary<string, int>();
tbNew.Add("cat", 1);
tbNew.Add("dog", 4);
```

Or ArrayList

```
ArrayList tbNew = new ArrayList();
tbNew.Add("cat");
tbNew.Add(2);
tbNew.Add(false);
```

Comment: -1 because OP hasn't asked for alternative options. He just want to know why simple Collection isn't working in c#

Comment: There is no Collection in Compact Framework, so I am not sure why you downvote this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give type to your collection in C# like

```
private Collection<string> tbNew  = new Collection<string>();
```

i have given string as an example. it is

```
Collection<T>
```

i.e. you can given any type.

**For Compact Framework you can use [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6918612z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) as an alternative**

Collection is supported in following Frameworks

```
.NET Framework
   Supported in: 4.5, 4, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0
.NET Framework Client Profile
   Supported in: 4, 3.5 SP1
 Portable Class Library
   Supported in: Portable Class Library
.NET for Windows Store apps
   Supported in: Windows 8
```

Comment: Doesn't work. There is not Collection in Compact Framework (at least I can not find one)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collection`
as

```
Private Collection<string> dinosaurs = new Collection<string>();
```

Check out this [Collection doc msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132400.aspx)

To initializes a new instance of the `Collection<T>` class that is empty. You can use this constructor

```
Collection<T>()
```

This will give you a whole idea about collections in c# check out this also [Collections in c#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Doesn't work. There is no Collection in compact edition. Only thing that I see is NameValueCollection, but I am not sure if this is the same or not.